# Select "many to many" and "belongs to" in single statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
user_playlist
-------------
user_id
playlist_id

user
-------------
id
name

playlist
-------------
id
user_id
name
```

Broken down, playlists can be either public (assigned to users using the junction table) or private (belonging to a user by setting the playlists user_id). How can I query all playlists for a user in a single select? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. It `JOIN`s `user` to `playlist`, either via `user_playlist` (for public playlists) or directly (for private playlists):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_playlist up ON up.user_id = u.id
JOIN playlist p ON p.id = up.playlist_id OR p.user_id = u.id
```

You can just add an appropriate `WHERE` clause (e.g. `u.id = 4` or `u.name = 'bill'`) to select the user of interest.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5f4caffd3c7f17cfdbcb9947e7207a19)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggests `exists`:

```
select pl.*
from playlist pl
where pl.user_id = :user or
      exists (select 1
              from user_playlist upl
              where upl.play_list_id = pl.id and
                    upl.user_id = :user
             );
```

The `user` table is not actually needed for this, unless you want to run the query for *all* users or you need to access the name.  Your question seems to be about only one user at a time.

Comment: That is correct. For accessing all playlists of all users, I simply select from the playlist table.